# ng-repeat with ng-switch: Need to call service in anchor. How?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a SPA set up with some complex code.  First, i am making a call to a service to get some data and binding it to a scope object.  Code example below:

```
    $scope.tables.outgoingCommunication = {
        columns: OutgoingCommunicationModel.columns,
        rows: []
    };
    $scope.getOutgoingDocs = () => {
        myService.GetPrintHistory($scope.item.ItemId, $scope.item.ItemDesc, $scope.oDocAge).success((response) => {
            $scope.tables.outgoingCommunication.rows = response.Response.body.Value;
        });
    };
```

My HTML has this code to bind to the outgoingCommunication table:

```
<section ng-if="tables.outgoingCommunication.rows.length" table-directive="outgoingCommunication" rows="tables.outgoingCommunication.rows" columns="tables.outgoingCommunication.columns" sort-field="'DatePosted'" descending="true" parent-method="toggleAge()" table-template="Templates/app/items/Outgoing-Communication.html"></section>
```

The template has this code in it:

```
<div id="outgoing-communication" class="table-responsive">
<div class="table container-fluid overflow-scroll" >

    <!--Header Row-->
    <div class="thead row tr hidden-xs">
        <div ng-repeat="column in columns" class="{{column.columnSize}} th" ng-class="{'overflow-ellipsis': column.allowTruncate == true}" ng-click="column.sortable && Sort(column.field)">
            {{column.title}} <i ng-if="column.sortable == true" ng-class="{'icon icon-caret-down inactive': sortField != column.field, 'icon icon-caret-down': descending && sortField == column.field, 'icon icon-caret-up': !descending && sortField == column.field}"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Body Rows-->
    <div ng-repeat="row in rows | orderBy:sortField:descending" class="row tr">
        <div>
            <!--Switch Case-->
            <div ng-switch="column.field" ng-repeat="column in columns" class="{{column.columnSize}} td" ng-class="{'overflow-ellipsis': column.allowTruncate == true}">
                <b class="visible-xs-inline-block">{{column.title}} </b>
                <!--When Actions-->
                <div ng-switch-when="Actions">
                    <a href="#">View&nbsp;<i class="icon icon-lg icon-file-o"></i> </a>
                </div>
                <!--When DatePosted-->
                <div ng-switch-when="DatePosted">
                    {{row[column.field] | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}
                </div>
                <!--When Default-->
                <div ng-switch-default>{{row[column.field]}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<a ng-if="$parent.oDocAge == 1" href="" ng-click="parentMethod()">View More</a>
<a ng-if="$parent.oDocAge == 3" href="" ng-click="parentMethod()">View Less</a>
</div>
```

The data I am getting back from the call to GetPrintHistory has a JSON format as follows:

```
{
FormNumber: "1060",
FormDescription: "Invoice",
PrintProcessId: 6440187,
DatePosted: "2014-12-20T00:00:00",
PrintXMLId: 5286992,
ItemImageNum: 26
}
```

There is a series of these items in the collection.

My model is defined as:

```
 define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    var OutgoingCommunicationModel;
    (function (OutgoingCommunicationModel) {
        OutgoingCommunicationModel.columns = function () {
            return [
        {
            field: "DatePosted",
            title: "Date Posted",
            columnSize: "col-sm-3",
            allowTruncate: true,
            sortable: true
        },
        {
            field: "FormDescription",
            title: "Description",
            columnSize: "col-sm-3",
            allowTruncate: false,
            sortable: true
        },
        {
            field: "Actions",
            columnSize: "col-sm-3",
            allowTruncate: false,
            sortable: false
        }
            ];
        };
    })(OutgoingCommunicationModel|| (OutgoingCommunicationModel= {}));
    return OutgoingCommunicationModel;
});
```

My current code is displaying the FormDescription column and DatePosted field with no problem.  The problem is the Actions column.  I need to have the anchor call a service method defined below:

```
    this.GetOutgoingDocument = function (itemId, itemImageNumber, printProcessId, printXmlId) {
        return _this.$http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "api/item/GetOutgoingDocument",
            params: { itemId: itemId, itemImageNumber: itemImageNumber, printProcessId: printProcessId, printXmlId: printXmlId }
        });
    };
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to set up the call in the ng-repeat with the ng-switch-when embedding to call the service method.  If I need to, I can try and build a codepen or something to get a sample set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there were a few ways I needed to face this.

1. The table directive I was using to open the template and display the data had an isolated scope.  To get around this, I added a scope variable `externalCall: "&"` and set up my section tag that called this directive as follows: `external-call="selectRow(itemId,itemImageNum, printProcessId, printXMLId)"`.  Finally, I used this in my anchor code: `<a ng-click="externalCall({itemId: row.ItemId, itemImageNum: row.ItemImageNum, printProcessId: row.PrintProcessId, printXMLId: row.PrintXMLId})">View&nbsp;<i class="icon icon-lg icon-file-o"></i> </a>`
2. As you can see in the code above, I discovered the row variable held all the data i needed from my row that was returned.

In the long run, I ended up having to take a slightly different route.  Since I am returning a PDF from the Web API call, I instead moved over to ng-href to call the API call directly.

```
<a target="_blank" ng-href="api/policy/GetOutgoingDocument?itemId={{row.ItemId}}&itemImageNum={{row.ItemImageNum}}&printProcessId={{row.PrintProcessId}}&printXMLId={{row.PrintXMLId}}">View&nbsp;<i class="icon icon-lg icon-file-o"></i> </a>
```

I will need to do something about the Web API call though.  If I get an error, I am seeing an Ajax document showing a 400 error on it.  I want to handle it differently than that.  May have to ask a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ng-init?

```
<div ng-switch-when="Actions">
      <a href="#" ng-init="GetOutgoingDocument(....)">View&nbsp;<i class="icon icon-lg icon-file-o"></i> </a>
</div>
```

This could work if you want the service called when switching, if you want the service called when clicking a button you could use ng-click = "GetOutgoingDocument()"

This is assuming you have GetOutgoingDocument on the $scope.

Comment: The problem I am concerned about more than anything is how to get the values that were returned from the ajax call.  It seems the ng-switch-when calls make the column.field value be the column in question.  I'm trying to figure out how to get the other column values when under the Actions item.